# Fluentd installation failed with message in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, fluentd

I'm doing testing Fluentd for collecting log files from Apache Tomcat in Windows OS.
So, I tried install with **[Fluentd-Packages v5.x]** and **[Calyptia-Fluent v1.3.x]** and failed with Windows Message that **"Setup Wizard ended prematurely"** like below :

[image]

I tried in 5 Windows boxes and only success in 1 Windows box. different thing is Windows Update and installed .NET framework only

```
1. Succeed Windows : didn't update from 1st installation
2. Other Windows : did update all windows
```

Finally, I couldn't found any clues for solve.
I need windows and Fluentd, Ruby experts help. if you have knowledge, share to me please.
Thank you.